# Flutter embedding not working since 3.3.0 release

Tags: android, flutter

We have some flutter module for a very specific part in our app that (thanks to flutter embedding) we share between oud Android and iOS app.

That used to work pretty well. However since we are trying to upgrade flutter to the latest version 3.3.0 we are getting all kind of weird errors regarding duplicate classes, but the strange thing is it is only in our debug build of the app. Not in the release build of the app!

Our debug flutter module is embedded (aar) in our Android app through Gradle (see config below). However I already tried replacing the debug flutter module by the release flutter module but no difference. The debug build keeps failing...

```
     Duplicate class io.flutter.view.VsyncWaiter$1 found in modules jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25) and jetified-flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25)
     Duplicate class io.flutter.view.VsyncWaiter$1$1 found in modules jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25) and jetified-flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25)
     Duplicate class io.flutter.view.VsyncWaiter$DisplayListener found in modules jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25) and jetified-flutter_embedding_release-1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25 (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_release:1.0.0-857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25)
```

```
    debugImplementation 'com.company.module:flutter_debug:+'
    releaseImplementation 'com.company.module:flutter_release:+'
```

Since the release build is working fine I was checking both the module (which builds does not fail at all, but results in AAR files) if there was any special obfuscation/proguard config but I cannot find anything that is different between the two builds that might cause this issue…

Downgrading back to 3.0.0 works without any issues (with 100% exact same config).

Anyone any clue?

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution to this? I am also facing the same for flutter 3.3.9

Comment: @PrateekSharma So far not, we are currently 'distracted' with another side project and we keep building this Flutter project on Flutter 3.0.0 for now. If you have a clean project setup to reproduce this you can submit a bug request to the flutter team. I already did but without the clean setup (did not find the time to build one from scratch) and so the issue was not accepted...